# Logic for all possible scenarios paypal IPN

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

Okay so I'm currently writing my IPN page, got it all to work for inserting to the db when `payment_status` is completed. Here is my query thus far:

```
if($payment_status=="Completed"){
        $txn_id_check = $mysqli->query("SELECT `transaction_id` FROM `payment` WHERE `transaction_id`='$txn_id'");
        if($txn_id_check->num_rows != 1) {  
                    $query = "INSERT INTO `payment` (`transaction_id`, `payment_status`, `users_id`) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
                    $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);
                    $statement->bind_param('ssi',$txn_id, $payment_status, $id);
                    if($statement->execute()){
                    print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is : ' .$statement->insert_id .'<br />'; 
                    }else{
                    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
                    }
                    $statement->close();
        }
    }
```

Because I'm making a subscription service I'm unsure as to **all** the scenarios that could happen. My thoughts:

**User Buys Membership**

- User makes purchase for premium membership ( subscribes )
- Add their data to the database
- Update their account to premium

*Checks: Must check payment is to correct recepient, transaction_id doesnt exist, the payment amount is correct.*

**User Cancels Membership**

- User cancels membership through paypal ( unsubscribes )
- update the database against their transaction id
- Downgrade their account to non-premium

Is there anything else I need to consider?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @AndrewAngell Reckon you could give me a few pointers?